# flash movie won't load? linking issue?

Tags: flash, url, .htaccess, hyperlink, embed

artoferichu.com/figures/ doesn't load.
artoferichu.com/figures loads.

the flash movie won't load in the first link and loads in the second link. any idea what is going on??

i'm using .htaccess to redirect figures to figures.php

oh btw, my .htacces looks like this: RewriteRule ^figures/?$  figures.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading the Flash file using a relative path, which is resolved relative to the folder in the URL.

With the trailing slash, the URL is interpreted as a folder named `/figures/`, without a filename.
Therefore, it tries to load load the Flash file from `http://artoferichu.com/figures/figures.swf`.

Without the trailing slash, the URL is interpreted as a file named `figures` in the root folder.
Therefore, it tries to load load the Flash file from `http://artoferichu.com/figures.swf`.

To fix it, you can either change the page to load the Flash file from an absolute path (`/Figures.swf`) or add a redirect rule for `/figures/figures.swf`.

Comment: i tried to change all the links to ../figures.swf and even tried to link directly to the flash movie with the full URL. but it's still not loading